# Spring request scoped bean failed to be autowired within @Around

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scope, autowired

I am trying to create a bean that is valid only for a single request that contains a user's roles. I will populate the roles in an @Around method prior to calling any controller methods. I then need to access these roles later for other authorization checks.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class SecurityAudit {

    @Autowired
    private CurrentRoles currentRoles;


    @Around("@annotation(requestMapping) && execution( * 
com.myapp.controller..*.*(..))")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, RequestMapping requestMapping) 
throws Throwable {  

       ...
       ...
       //I populate the roles with a db lookup. They will be referenced here, and later in controller methods as-needed.

    }
}

package com.myapp.model;

...
...

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"sso",
"roles"
})
@Component
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CurrentRoles {

    @JsonProperty("roles")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    ...
    ...

}
```

I get the following:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityAudit': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.model.CurrentRoles com.myapp.currentRoles; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.model.CurrentRoles] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The Aspect is created at startup. I would have though the injected request-scoped bean would stay null until requests start coming in, then I could populate the currentRoles bean for that specific request.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot @Service annotation in your Service class ;)